# dplyr::coalesce skip non-existent values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, coalesce

Is it actually possible to have `dplyr::coalesce()` skip non-existent values like e.g. colnames in this case? (e.g. `col2` doesn't exist in `data`)

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    var_1 = coalesce(col1, col2,...,coln),
    var_n = ...)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. You can use built-in data set e.g. `cars` to give a first example on what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all possible column names into a character vector in advance, then use `any_of()` to select columns. If some column names do not exist, `any_of()` will skip them.

```r
library(dplyr)

vars <- paste0("col", 1:10)
# [1] "col1"  "col2"  "col3"  "col4"  "col5"  "col6"  "col7"  "col8"  "col9"  "col10"

data %>%
  mutate(
    var_1 = do.call(coalesce, pick(any_of(vars)))
  )
```

---

If `col1` to `coln` are in sequence, you can simply use `col1:coln` to select variables lying between `col1` on the left and `coln` on the right.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(
    var_1 = do.call(coalesce, pick(col1:col10))
  )
```

Comment: An alternative is `coalesce(!!!select(., any_of(vars)))`. See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/funs/issues/54) for discussion

Comment: @Maël It's great! Actually I'm just confused why `coalesce(!!!pick(any_of(vars)))` does not work. That's also discussed in that link you gave.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, but your example throws ```Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"
> ```

Comment: @shizzle When you test my code, you should replace `data` with your real data object.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, it's way too early here, sorry. It actually worked with my data now. Thank you very much.